How to prove this random variable is sub-gaussian?
Consider
$$\sum_{i\in[n]}a_i c_i$$ where each $a_i=1$ with probability $p$ and $a_i=-1$ with probability $1-p$, and $a_1,\cdots,a_n$ are independent; Each $c_i$ is a fixed constant $\in(-1,0)$.
I would like to know its tail probability thus I was wondering how to prove this is sub-gaussian variable, so that I can use tail probability of sub-gaussian.
The second question is, since $a_ic_i$ is bounded, we could also use Bernstein inequality, then which one we should use?

One equivalent definition of sub-gaussian is that $X$ is sub-gaussian iff there exists $K_1>0$ such that for all $t\geqslant 0$, $$\mathbb{P}(|X|\geqslant t)\leqslant 2\exp(-t^2/K_1^2).$$ If $T>0$ is such that $\mathbb{P}(|X|\leqslant T)=1$, then for any $K>0$, $$\mathbb{P}(|X|\geqslant t)=0\leqslant 2\exp(-t^2/K^2)$$ whenever $t>T$. Then if $K_1=T/\sqrt{\log(2)}$, for $0\leqslant t\leqslant T$, $$\mathbb{P}(|X|\geqslant t) \leqslant 1=2\exp(-T^2/K_1^2)\leqslant 2\exp(-t^2/K_1^2).$$

Let $X_i = a_ic_i$. Note that each $X_i$ is clearly bounded, hence subGaussian. Sum of sub-Gaussian random variables is sub-Gaussian. Bernstein is a better choice when the variance is low, i.e., $p$ is close to $0$ or $1$. Otherwise, both are roughly the same.

@sudeep5221 how about when deviation $t$ is equal to expectation? would Bernstein still be better? Thank you!
